# Flag patients lost to follow-up after their first event

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

I’m trying to find patients who lost to follow-up (either permanently or temporarily) after their first event. So, we have an event date (edate) and total days of being registered for each year (regdays_09 to regdays_12). I want to flag patients who registered less than 365 days per year or have missing registered year. I much appreciate any help with this.

```
data Want;  
informat edate date7.;  
format edate date7.;  
input ID edate regdays_09 regdays_10 regdays_11 regdays_12 flag  
CARDS;  
100 06jan09 365  365  365   365  0   
101 10APR09 365  365   .      .  1  
102 23Mar09 180   .    .      .  1  
103 03Sep09 365   .   365   365  1  
104 20Aug09 300   .     .   365  1  
run;
```

Comment: First think about how you would do it by hand. Try to draw an decision tree than implement it. (if else you know it)

Comment: Thanks Lee. I think the decision is kind of straightforward: If a person had no complete followup (days) after the event then flagged. The problem for me is how to calculate the total followup times after the event time (which is variable for each person) and calculate subtract it from the sum of the followup days when they are stored in different columns (regdays_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all! Based on the comments I received here and also a comment from ShiroAmanda on another question, I got the following code that is what I wanted:

```
data have;  
informat edate date7.;  
format edate date7.;  
input ID edate regdays_09 regdays_10 regdays_11 regdays_12;
CARDS;  
100 06jan09 365  365  365   365 
101 10APR09 365  365   .      . 
102 23Mar09 180   .    .      . 
103 03Sep09 365   .   365   365 
104 20Aug10 300   .     .   365 
105 10Sep12  .   365  365   365
106 12sep11  .   360  365   360
 run;

data want (drop=x i mval: start);
  set have;
ARRAY Mval {4} (2009,2010,2011,2012); 
ARRAY Mvar {4}  regdays_09 regdays_10 regdays_11 regdays_12; 
do i=1 to dim(mval);
  if year(edate)=mval(i) then 
    do x=i to dim(mval); start=i;
      totalsum=sum(totalsum,mvar(x));
    end; 
    if totalsum<(dim(mval)-start+1)*365 then flag=1;else flag=0;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
data have;  
informat edate date7.;  
format edate date7.;  
input ID edate regdays_09 regdays_10 regdays_11 regdays_12;
CARDS;  
100 06jan09 365  365  365   365 
101 10APR09 365  365   .      . 
102 23Mar09 180   .    .      . 
103 03Sep09 365   .   365   365 
104 20Aug09 300   .     .   365 
run;

data want;
   set have;
   flag = (sum(of regdays:) ne 4*365);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you draycut! this works if all event times are in year 2009. But they could be any year. For example, id=105 have edate=10Apr11 with regdays_11=180 and missing in 2012. So I need to incorporate the event time into the calculation. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: So in that case, you want regdays_11 and regdays_12 both to be 365, otherwise it should be flagged, right? And we do not consider regdays_09 and regdays_10 then..

Comment: Yes, we don not consider regdays_09 and regdays_10 because they were before the event date. We want to flag this case (id=105) if the regdays_11<365-100 (or 31Dec11-10Apr11) and regdays_12<365. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First think 2012 has 366 days so all you patients failed. You could write an decision tree that can be implemented as an bunch of nested IF-THEN-ELSE.
if the first year has one or more days we have to check that all the next years are filled completely. If the first years have no days recorded do the do the same for the next year and so on.

```
IF regdays_09>0 THEN DO;
  IF regdays_10=365 AND regdays_11=365 AND regdays_12=366 THEN flag=0;
  ELSE flag=1;
END;ELSE IF regdays_10>0 THEN DO;
  IF regdays_11=365 AND regdays_12=366 THEN flag=0;
  ELSE flag=1;
END;ELSE IF regdays_11>0 THEN DO;
  IF regdays_12=366 THEN flag=0;
  ELSE flag=1;
END;ELSE flag=0;
```

Now when you become more advanced in programming you can try the same with nested loops.

Comment: Thank you. I need to count the number of 365 (or 366) days after the event date, not all years. So, for a person like id=105, regdays_09=300, regdays_10=., regdays_11=., regdays_12=366, since they have the full followup after the event year, they flagged 0, even 2009 was not complete, and 2010 & 2011 were missing.

Comment: That was not visible from the test data. But you could incorporate the YEAR function in the upper code to meet the requirements. You have to replace the greater than expression.